# In Swift/SwiftUI, when we use structs such as Text, or Image, are the considered instances? How?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

For example Text is considered a struct in SwiftUI. But you can modify the color **without** creating an object.

** If you change the background color of a View (just as an example) in UIKit, you tap into the color property of an **object**, But in SwiftUI, it's like I am tapping into properties of a struct which feels impossible.
For example to change the View in UIKit,

```
view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = .red
```

-- This makes perfect sense to me

This following example does not make sense to me. I can memorize the syntax, but it doesn't make sense:

```
Text("Hello world!")
  .background(Color.red)
```

So my question is, exactly what am I tapping into? Am I actually tapping into a property of a struct? In the SwiftUI example, Text is a struct, but I am using the dot syntax changing properties?

Comment: I wouldn't characterize them as instances. All SwiftUI does is describe the UI (this is why it is a *declarative* layout). Then, the system renders the UI based on that description. As opposed to the imperative style like UIKit/AppKit

Comment: In swift `.` syntax is used and for property access and for function call. In this case it is function call. "Instance-Class" is from OOP terminology... SwiftUI is actually uses many concepts of functional programming, so using "Value-Type" is more appropriate (actually it is similar to "1-Int" - we don't call 1 instance of Int, right?).

Comment: .modifiers refer to extensions not functions/methods inside an Object. UIKit is similar to JSwing/Old Xamarin aka old/legacy way of building UI. You create your UI the same way as you create an instance which is so much complicated and requires more lines of codes. If you have experience in Kotlin or other functional programming or modern framework, SwiftUI makes more sense in term of building UI, plus it requires less code too.

Answer (score 2):

> Text is a struct, but I am using the dot syntax changing properties?

`Text` is a `struct`, but `Text("Hello world!")` is a new instance of that `Text` type. It's absolutely no different than your `UIView` example.

You're calling the `background(_:)` method on that new instance, and it's returning a new view.

View modifiers are nothing special. They're just methods (typically on the `SwiftUI.View` protocol) which wrap `self` and return a new instance of some special view type which changes how the content is rendered.

It's pretty easy to see for yourself:

```
// SwiftUI.Color is a struct, but let's just simplify down to an enum.
enum MyColor { case red, green, blue }

protocol MyView {}

extension MyView {
    func background(_ color: MyColor) -> any MyView {
        ViewWithBackground(content: self, backgroundColor: color)
    }
}

struct MyText: MyView {
    let content: String
    
    init(_ content: String) { self.content = content }
}

struct ViewWithBackground<Content: MyView>: MyView {
    let content: Content
    let backgroundColor: MyColor
}

let view = MyText("Hello world!")
    .background(MyColor.red)
    
print(view)
```

Comment: FYI there is a ViewModifier protocol you can use

Comment: @malhal I omitted that detail, just to produce a really barebones example that illustrates the point